# Use variable in file path

Tags: python, import, export

I have a simple python script that requires an excel file input from a folder and then exports multiple documents to the same folder. Each time I use the script I have to change just one folder for each input and export line. Below is an example of the original input and one of the outputs. Each time I have to change the folder that is located as the last folder in the file path which is 05_psc_04 below.

```
reference = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\BarrettHedges\Dropbox (QUANTEO)\13_DATA_SERVICES\01_NA_CLIENT FILES\00_RECONSTRUCTION\05_psc_04\reference.xlsx")

export_test = test.to_excel(r'C:\Users\BarrettHedges\Dropbox (QUANTEO)\13_DATA_SERVICES\01_NA_CLIENT FILES\00_RECONSTRUCTION\05_psc_04\test.xlsx')
```

I would like to create a variable that I change each time at the beginning of the script like:

```
folder = "05_psc_04"
```

and my import and export line would then just have:

```
reference = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\BarrettHedges\Dropbox (QUANTEO)\13_DATA_SERVICES\01_NA_CLIENT FILES\00_RECONSTRUCTION\'folder'\reference.xlsx")
```

I'm clearly very novice at all of this, so any advice or way of doing this is GREATLY appreciated.

Cheers and thank you in advance

Comment: Will you use or treat all of 'em in the same way?

Comment: all of them as in each export?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to do simple string-formatting:

```
for folder_name in "first", "second", "third":
    path = "C:/users/test/desktop/{}/file.txt".format(folder_name)
    print(path)
```

Output:

```
C:/users/test/desktop/first/file.txt
C:/users/test/desktop/second/file.txt
C:/users/test/desktop/third/file.txt
>>>
```

Or, using an f-string:

```
for folder_name in "first", "second", "third":
    path = f"C:/users/test/desktop/{folder_name}/file.txt"
    print(path)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Paul. I'm really not sure how this applies - maybe I'm missing something. Each time only one folder in the file path changes. Each time I perform this operation (run this script) I manually have to change this one folder for the import and the 3 exports. Instead of changing the folder for each line, I want to just write the name of the folder once and it is automatically applied. Does that make sense?